# How to match and capture all ORed regular expressions from beginning of a string

Tags: php, python, regex, recursion, preg-match

I have a string `foobar1234`. And I want to capture the following strings from it.

1. foobar
2. bar1234
3. r1
4. ar12
5. foo

I have written multiple regexes for each and ORed them together as follows:

```
/(f.+r)|(b.+4)|(r1)|(a.+2)|(f.+o)/
```

But it only matches and captures the first regex i.e, (f.+r). How can I capture remaining expressions?

Comment: I'm using preg_match_all but the question was about matching each of ORed expression from beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
(?=(f.+r)|(b.+4)|(r1)|(a.+2))
```

PHP:

```
$str = 'foobar1234';
preg_match_all('/(?=(?|(f.+r)|(b.+4)|(r1)|(a.+2)))/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: thanks. It solved mostly but I have another case where it didn't work. I have updated the question to reflect my needs.